# Hide and show dialogs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is when you click on a button that has the class ".option" it will show the div that has the id "#dialog" and then it will add the class .active to the button clicked (there maybe more than one button that shows different dialogues later one) as well as adding the class ".noScroll" to the body. When the dialogue is shown it can be closed by clicking anywhere on the "#dialog" but NOT the ".dialogPage" which is the div that is inside the "#dialog" div. If the dialogue has been closed, the class that has been added to the body and to the button shall be removed.

Here is the button that need to be clicked to show the dialog:

```
<a class="option" href="edit_account.php">Your Account</a>
```

The following HTML represents the structure of my Dialog:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <div id="dialogPage" class="dialogPage">
           <p>Edit your account here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the related CSS:

```
body {
    color: #4A4A4A;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    font-family: 'arial', sans-serif; 
    font-size: 0.95em;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;  
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#dialog {
    display: none;
    background-color: rgba(25,30,37,0.95);
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom:0; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;    
    margin-top: 70px;
    z-index: 900;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}

    .dialogPage {
        background-color: #F7F7F7;
        border: 2px solid #ffffff;

        width: 900px; min-width: 900px; 
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 50px auto;  

        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }


.noScroll {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

Here is the JavaScript I am currently using, but please do not built on it as it is wrong I am sure:

```
$(".option, #dialog").on('click', function() {
    $("#dialog").toggle(29);
    $("body").toggleClass("noScroll");

     if (e.target.id != 'dialogPage' && !$('#dialogPage').find(e.target).length) {
        $("#dialog").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('.option').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').show();
    $('body').addClass('noScroll');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return false;
});

$('#dialog').click(function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
    $('body').removeClass('noScroll');
    $('.option').removeClass('active');
});

$('#dialogPage').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I didn't see any use of the `.active` class in your current code, so that is just a guess.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/verashn/2Xh7d/